# SharpDX - AssetNotFoundException

Tags: sharpdx

Sorry to raise this question again as I see it has been asked a few times however the solutions have not helped me.

The code I am trying to get to work is one of the sample examples, desktop version of SpriteBatchAndFont https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/tree/master/Toolkit/WindowsDesktop/SpriteBatchAndFont

My particular problem is that font Arial16.xml and the balls.dds image raise the AssetNotFoundException.

From previous posts I have noted and checked the set up of a relative directory for loading contents - Content.RootDirectory = "Content"; and checked that the font and the image are in that named dir. Further I have noted and checked that the Build Action is set to ToolkitFont and ToolkitTexture for the font and texture respectively.

I have also read that the project may need to be in the %Documents% folder (do not understand why that would be, but tested it anyway) and also that the Contents folder may not have the required Windows permissions.

It may well be something simple that I am not aware of but I have been at this for a few days and have now run out of ideas and googling ability. I would be grateful for any help or pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wasted hours triying to figure it out, as all official examples and tutorials on web doesn't mention that.
Changing directory to `Content.RootDirectory = @"\Content";` finally worked for me.